# How can I use if else with question mark properly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achieve the rating star for user with the question mark if else condition but it seems like not working.

Here is my code base:

```
 const totalRating = (Ratings.reduce((total, rating) => parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(rating.skillset_rating), 0) / Ratings.length) || 0;

    <div className="user_rating_review">
      <span className="user_rating_data_name">Reviews:</span>
    {
        userObj.Skills ?
        <div className="review_rating_star">
            <Rating value={totalRating} precision={0.5} readOnly max={5} className="user_rating_found" />
            <span className="user_total_rating">{totalRating}</span>/5
        </div>
        : <div className="review_unspecified">Not enough rating yet</div>
    }
    </div>
```

and here is how my project look like:

[image]

so when the user have 0/5 reviews. It should return "Not enough rating yet" but instead it return me a number 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have `userObj.Skills ?` instead of `totalRating ? `. Is this a typo, or is it intended?

Comment: What value does `userObj.Skills` contain?

Comment: your usage seems fine, you probably want to replace `userObj.Skills`

Comment: perhaps you want to check userObj.skills > 0 ? if it contains a value, because now you check if skill exists or if skill does not exist.

Comment: Oh i did `const { Ratings, Skills } = userObj;`